# Localization doesn't work when root-namespace is different

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

I have two projects
Shared.csproj
which has

Shared --
--Resources
-----Resource.cs(with namespace Xyz.Shared.Resources)
-----Resource.en.resx

Another project which references this shared project but is not able to find the resource

Localization
---Startup.cs (with namespace Localization)
---Controllers
-----ValuesController.cs(using string localizer to find the resource)
In startup.cs

```
        services.AddLocalization(opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "");
        services.AddScoped<IStringLocalizer, StringLocalizer<Resource>>();

        services
            .Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var cultures = new[]
                           {
                                   new CultureInfo("en"),
                                   new CultureInfo("ar")
                                       };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
            });
```

ValuesController.cs

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;
    public ValuesController(IStringLocalizer localizer)
    {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders =
  new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var header in Request.Headers)
        {
            requestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
        CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        var localizeString = this.localizer.GetString("admin");
        var r = localizeString.SearchedLocation;

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string name = assembly.GetName().Name;

        return new string[] { this.localizer.GetString("admin"), "value2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: This post may help you：https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/340